# jolt - copy or move a key from nested object to the top level

Tags: json, jolt

I'm looking for a way to copy or move a key from nested object to the top level

**Input**:

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "foo",
  "details": {
    "orderNumber": "456789",
    "addr": "N st 124",
    "date": "2021-01-01"
  }
}
```

**desired output**:

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "foo",
  "orderNumber": "456789",
  "details": {
    "orderNumber": "456789",
    "addr": "N st 124",
    "date": "2021-01-01"
  }
}
```

**or ideally**

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "foo",
  "orderNumber": "456789",
  "details": {
    "addr": "N st 124",
    "date": "2021-01-01"
  }
}
```

the closest I could get is below transformation, but it converts object to value array

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "name": "name",
      "details": {
        "orderNumber": "orderNumber",
        "*": "details"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close to the result, just a slight change(adding an ampersand) is needed such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "name": "name",
      "details": {
        "orderNumber": "orderNumber",
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in this case the keys keeps on appearing.